# Android Option Menu Default Overflow Icon Zoomed

Tags: android, toolbar, android-xml, optionmenu

The icon of overflow menu in following app is unusually big and I'm not even using custom icon. Any idea what cause it?

[image: unusually big overflow menu icon]
The following is the expected size of the icon
[image: expected size]
Edit: providing the menu xml (both have the same code for the UI)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_addContact"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Add"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_contact_add"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_searchContact"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_contact_search"
        myapp:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_register_CA"
        myapp:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Register CA"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_setting"
        myapp:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Setting"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_logout"
        myapp:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Logout"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Please paste your menu file.

Comment: added the xml code

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem
In AndroidManifest.xml there are these lines

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="false"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true">
```

Removing these lines solve my problem